# App Engine Endpoints: Javascript Client Library for OAuth2 authorisation requires multiple popups

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

Do I understand the concept behind client side authorization correctly: to make a request to my endpoints API I have to call

```
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: client_id,scope: scopes, immediate: false}, callback);
```

each time an oauth token expires, which triggers popup window. It seems to me that it won't make a great user experience. Are there any ways to bypass that flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's one nice solution I stumbled upon https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/sample-application#Enable_Authentication